# Most efficient way of using multidimensional array indexers

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, xna, accessor

Say you have a 2D grid of tiles (This is for a 2D tile based game), most tiles occupy 1 spot, however some larger "objects" can fill in multiple spots. I use an indexer on my array to automatically "refer" these objects to their base tile. So If I have a 2x2 object at 3,4, and I access 4,4, it will automatically redirect and get the tile at 3,4. However I can specify an argument to go around this functionality in the event that I need to get the exact tile. (Better explanation on [my old question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/33967/13911) on GameDev about this)

Another way to look at it is a door object in the game world, the user can click anywhere on it to open it, but each individual part can contain other properties, like different backgrounds and lighting values.

Note I am just a hobbyist programmer, so this may not be right (and why I am seeking your advice) Each "extra large" tile will store a reference to it's base tile in the form of a `X,Y` position (Should this instead be a reference to the actual object in memory?)

```
public class TileWrapper
{
    public int Width = 0;
    public int Height = 0;
    private Tile[] tiles; //Backing Store
    public TileWrapper()
    {
        tiles = new Tile[Width * Height]; 
    }
    public TileWrapper(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        tiles = new Tile[Width * Height];
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Accessor for tiles
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">X Position</param>
    /// <param name="y">Y Position</param>
    /// <param name="overide">Bool to "override" the get, if true, it wont get the reference tile and will bypass the checks</param>
    public Tile this[int x, int y, bool override = false]
    {
        get 
        {
             //If we do not want to bypass the checks, AND the current tile is > than 1x1
             if (!override && tiles[y * Width + x].IsLarge)
                return tiles[tiles[y * Width + x].refY * Width + tiles[y * Width + x].refX]; //Use the reference positions to get the main position of the tile
             //If we want to bypass the checks or the tile wasn't large, get the absolute position
             else 
                 return tiles[y * Width + x];
        }
        set 
        {
             //Same thing for SET
             if (!override && tiles[y * Width + x].IsLarge) //Set base tile if the large tile has a reference
                 tiles[tiles[y * Width + x].refY * Width + tiles[y * Width + x].refX] = value;
             else  //Set absolute tile
                  tiles[y * Width + x] = value;
        }
    }
```

Sorry if it is a bit hard to read with the 2D to 1D conversion, but after doing some testing it looks like using a 1D array internally is a bit faster.

`IsLarge` is a property that simply checks if a tile, well, is large (greater than 1x1)

I already have logic in place to fill the adjacent tile's references when a large tile is placed, and to remove them accordingly.

While profiling the game I found that the get accessor for the tile was eating up a lot of CPU, getting tiles hundreds of times per frame for lighting, rendering, collision, etc.

How can I improve the performance and efficiency of this code?

**Benchmarks** (Average of 30k iterations on an Intel Quad Core i7 2670QM)

`Tile t = tiles[100, 100];` - 160 ns and 175 ns WITH 2D Internal Array

`Tile t = tiles[100, 100, true];` - 137 ns and 264 ns WITH 2D Internal Array (odd)

`100,100` is not a large tile by the way, note that these tiles are not very common. I you had a house on screen, you could have a few large tiles (doors, tables), but lots of dirt/stone/wood.

Comment: My advice would be to overload the indexer instead of using a default parameter for the boolean. Perhaps use named methods for one or the other.  Then, you can eliminate the branching from your array access.

Comment: How long is code using this currently taking?  How long does it need to take in order to be "fast enough" for your purposes?  What indication do you have that this is currently a bottleneck in the performance of your application?

Comment: @lukegravitt I did that before, nothing gained/lost @ Servy Few minutes, I'll look back at the profiler results

Comment: Is Tile a struct or class?

Comment: I would definitely use a reference to the object in memory. That way you remove the extra calculations and recursive method calls.

Comment: @AlexDev Alright, I will do that. Also note that the references are rarely called, as the amount of large tile such as doors/tables compared to dirt/wood is very small

Comment: I would review your lighting / collision algorithms for efficiency.  Lighting, in particular, can be a huge performance problem.  You might be calling the get accessors more times than needed.

Comment: Lighting is only called when a new block is placed, I was just using that as an example, it isn't much of a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that for each collection of squares that are logically joined together you create an instance of something like:

```
private class TileRef { public Tile tile; public int X,Y,Width,Height;}
```

Then have either a 2-dimensional or jagged array of TileRef.  All of the squares in a joined-together group should hold a reference to the same `TileRef` object.  That should allow you to very quickly find the `TileRef` associated with any square on the board without need for conditional logic to deal with different-sized tiles.

To construct a grid of size-one tiles:

```
TileRef[,] tiles;
TileMapper(int xsize, int ysize)
{
  tiles = new TileRef[xsize,ysize];
  for (int x=0; x < xsize; x++)
    for (int y=0; y < xsize; y++)
    {
      var thisRef = new TileRef();
      thisRef.X = x;
      thisRef.Y = y;
      thisRef.Width = 1;
      thisRef.Height = 1;
      thisRef.Tile = new Tile(); // Make a default tile instance somehow
      tiles[x][y] = thisRef;
    }
}

To join a bunch of squares together into a blob:

public JoinSquares(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
      var thisRef = new TileRef();
      thisRef.X = x;
      thisRef.Y = y;
      thisRef.Width = 1;
      thisRef.Height = 1;
      thisRef.Tile = new Tile(); // Make a default tile instance somehow
      for (i=0; i<width; i++)
        for (j=0; j<height; j++)
          tiles[x+i,y+j] = thisRef;
}

public SeparateSquares(int x, int y)
{
      var oldRef = tiles[x,y];
      x=oldref.X;
      y=oldref.Y;
      var width=oldref.Width;
      var height=oldref.Height;

      for (i=0; i<width; i++)
        for (j=0; j<height; j++)
        {
          var thisRef = new TileRef();
          thisRef.X = x+i;
          thisRef.Y = y+j;
          thisRef.Width = 1;
          thisRef.Height = 1;
          thisRef.Tile = new Tile(); // Make a default tile instance somehow
          tiles[x+i,y+j] = thisRef;
        }
}

To change the `Tile` associated with a "blob", simply

public Tile this[int x, int y]
{
    get 
    {
        return tiles[x,y].Tile;
    }
    set
    {
        tiles[x,y].Tile = value;
    }
}
```

Loops are required to join squares together or separate them, but not to simply change the attributes associated with a blob by changing its `Tile` property.

Comment: I think you could just have a reference to the main `Tile` on the `Tile` class itself and it would just point to itself if `IsLarge` is false. There is no need for a 2nd set of data.

Comment: @lukegravitt: The second level of indirection is necessary if one wants a `set` method to be usable in the indicated fashion.  Otherwise, if there's a 3x3 tile with upperleft-corner at (3,6), trying to call `set` on coordinate (4,7) would cause that square to point to the new object, while the surrounding squares point to the old one.

Comment: The `set` method would definitely become more complicated in this case, but you don't necessarily need the next level.  You could get the referenced `Tile` and iterate over its extends, adjusting as necessary. This use case makes sense though, as you be effectively breaking the group up so every Tile needs to be visited.

Comment: @lukegravitt: If storing a `Tile` to a location is supposed to update all parts of the larger tile and there isn't an extra level of indirection, the mapping object will have to know which squares need updating.  Information used for that purpose should be "owned" by the mapping object; nothing else should be able to modify it.  Adding the second layer of indirection avoids the need for the loop, and allows the mapper object to keep its information private.

Comment: You would still need a loop with your solution. I do, however, agree with you. This entire setup would be much more efficient by using a `struct` for the Tiles and storing this adjacency information in a separate structure, especially considering that these larger tiles are fairly rare as stated in the question.

Comment: @lukegravitt: One would need a loop only in cases where one was altering the size of a square (which should be done in a method rather than a property setter).  Otherwise, writing to `tilerefs[x,y].tile` would in one operation change the `tile` associated with all the grid locations that should be altered.

Comment: If you can show me the code to do what you are suggesting without a loop, I will be impressed.